# *System.Text.Json* unable to load when VisualStudio is not installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I have a DLL based on *netcoreapp3.1*. The DLL references the NuGet package *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json version 5.0.0*. If I deploy the DLL to another PC where VisualStudio is not installed and try to access it from a third party program, I get the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Could not find or load a specific file. (0x80131621)
```

If I install VS on that PC, it works. If I uninstall VS the error appears again.

Apparently VS add some components that are needed for my DLL. How can I resolve that?

## Steps I Tried To Resolve

- I explicitly added the NuGet Package *System.Text.Json Version 5.0.2*. Error still appears.

## The .csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>Key.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <Version>1.0.3</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.2.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.3.0</FileVersion>
    <Copyright>ZOOM Informatik GmbH, Grenchen, Schweiz</Copyright>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="publish\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="publish\**" />
    <None Remove="publish\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="SapServiceReference\swagger.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <OpenApiReference Include="SapServiceReference\swagger.json" ClassName="SapServiceReference" CodeGenerator="NSwagCSharp" Namespace="SapService" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Client" Version="5.0.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.ApiDescription.Client" Version="13.13.2">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Why are you mixing .NET Core 3.1 packages with .NET 5 packages? You shouldn't install any Microsoft.Extensions.* package greater than 3.x.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check dependencies: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/

this version requires for you to use one of:

- .net framework >= 4.6.1
- .net standard >= 2.0
- .net core 5.0

so if you have requirements for netcoreapp3.1 you need to use the version 3.1.20 or lower

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto obviously, but keep in mind it was not standard which was running so the context of the dependency was not standard but 3.1 because of which project brought in the dependency presumably

Comment: I choose to read that it makes no sense to You ;) let me explain, so the LTS version of the .net core runtime is the 3.1 version and when you compile you'll ask for -framework netcoreapp3.1 and you will notice this is the case here.
so what i am aiming at is that this is what you can see in the project file, so considerations about newer versions of .net isn't really in scope.
I included the requirements like you would've noticed from the link before concluding the written making no sense, to give options. eg. move dependency to a standard library as opposed to downgrading ref.

Comment: Please observe that the community member who had the problem got helped to get it resolved with the suggestion, so obviously it made sense there.
To reiterate, it is bluntly stated in the dependency that there be no support for .net core 3.1 it is not hidden but in plain sight.
In the members case the reference is obviously in the .net core 3.1 assembly  and not in a .net standard any version. I did provide a link to where on NuGet one can see the compatibility list and I even copied it in :) references can be confusing I agree but with experience you'll know where to look and we have to.

Answer (score 0):

for my project when I upgrade .net version from 4.5 to 4.6 it' Ok

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31719850)